# Use makefile variables inside tcsh

Tags: makefile, tcsh

I created a `tcsh` script, which I want to call through a `Makefile` environment. Therefore
I want to reference variables inside this tcsh script, which I have defined in the `Makefile` environment.
I tried to reference environment variables as `$?VARIABLE`, but this does not work on variables from the `Makefile` environment.
How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GNU make, [you need to `export` the variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html).

Comment: Thanks! They were already exported, but I forgot to call them while running the script!

Answer (score 1):

Any dollar sign needs to be represented as a `$$` in a make rule if it is to be used in commands. Note that [it is extremely unwise to program in tcsh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). In addition, make uses `/bin/sh` to execute commands, so you cannot use tcsh syntax in make rules.

All you could do, if you must, is something along

```
 MAKEVAR = foo
 target:
       tcsh -c 'echo $$HOME $(MAKEVAR)'
```

What everybody else does is

```
 MAKEVAR    = foo
 ANOTHERVAR = bar
 target:
       MAKEVAR=$(MAKEVAR) ANOTHERVAR=$(ANOTHERVAR) script.sh
```

This works for all `make` versions, not just GNU make.

Comment: Well ... certainly, sh and bash are much better as scripting languages.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but why should I write the script all over again if it's working perfectly in tcsh?

Comment: To save you from trouble later on. Being proficient in sh scripting is a very good investment. Using tcsh is what brought you here; it is not the last bump you will run into.

Comment: You're right. Personally I prefer sh and bash, but this script is not mine and I just wanted to use it as it is...

Comment: Okay. You *can* actually use the same line with `script.tcsh` instead of `script.sh` because `/bin/sh` called by make assigns the variables and then the kernel starts tcsh (assuming your script.tcsh starts with `#!/bin/tcsh` or similar).